# Numbering Selection in Particular Order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, numbering

I am needing to number a selection of points following a street or set of streets using an alpha-numeric string from A001-Z999. And while I'm trying to figure out how to get these points numbered using only odd numbers (ie A001, A003, A005); more importantly, I'm needing to communicate to ArcGIS that I want them numbered starting at a certain point on the street and following the trail of selections.

I'll be needing to duplicate this process with each new, unique strand of selected points and assume each strand will travel in multiple directions. Is there a way to do this specifically within Field Calculator?

[image]

Comment: Do these points have a common route number? If so you could make a dict in python for each route number and starting point ID. Then loop through the dict selecting the current route number and finding it's nearest point using "arcpy.PointDistance_analysis" and then move on to the nearest point after that and so on. Have a counter start and reset with each start id and use update cursor for each time the loop iterates. You may want to use a conditional with street names. Can only give concept since you did not provide code.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking for. The simplest way to describe and perform it would be to take a selection of points (pre-existing) on street Anywhere Ave (which runs east and west) and somehow tell the Field Calculator: "label these points starting at the eastern most selection, and do so using only odd numbers from A005-A105. Does that make more sense?